# How do I select unique, most recently inserted, values from a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database

My table(*products*) looks like this:

```
id name value
1  oil  100
2  oil  140
3  glue 120
4  glue 110
```

I need to select last inserted *oil* and last inserted *glue*, so result should be:

```
2 oil 140
4 glue 110
```

what have i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY `value` DESC LIMIT 2
```

but this query shows

```
1  oil  100
3  glue 120
```

Comment: Your query is quite ok. You use ID instead of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the last inserted row of each type (highest id), then retrieve the data for those ids. This assumes your id numbers go up with each new insertion, so a higher id value assumes a later insert.

```
 SELECT d.id, d.name, d.value
   FROM products d
   JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(id) id, name
       FROM products
      GROUP BY name
   ) m ON (d.id = m.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
SELECT * FROM `products` GROUP BY `name` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: PLease ignore this eyes went funny

Answer (score 1):

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM products a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
                 FROM products
                 GROUP BY name
                ) b
                ON a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: ofc but i need to wait 3 more minutes :>

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do a self-join on the table:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name, p1.value
FROM products p1
inner join 
(
   select name, max(id) mxid
   from products
   group by id
) p2
   on p1.name = p2.name
   and p1.id = p2.mxid
```

The inner subquery gets the `max()` id of the records and then you join that back on the table to return the record you want.